# Unresolved overloading error in Haskell

Tags: haskell, overloading

```
getNext a = if even a then a/2 else (3*a)+1
```

for some reason this line of code returns an unresolved overloading error.

```
Main> getNext 13
ERROR - Unresolved overloading
*** Type       : (Fractional a, Integral a) => a
```

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing? I haven't used Haskell in quite some time so I might have forgotten a few things.

Comment: The error means: "You want a type that satisfies both the constraint `Fractional` and `Integral` but I don't know any type that does." Moreover this probably has also to do with defaulting (which is used in `Num` contexts), so the problem is also that `13` is polymorphic and `getNext` is polymorphic too, so even having a type that has both instances you'd get an error similar to doing things like: `show . read`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want

```
a `div` 2
```

rather than

```
a/2
```

The error is happening because `even a` implies that `a` is an integer, but the use of the non-integer division operator `/` implies otherwise.